# Deleting resources attached to azure virtual machine using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, shell, virtual-machine, azure-cli, azure-resource-group

I'm writing a shell script for deleting azure virtual machine and its associated resources, but having issues getting vm's network security group name/ids and vm's public ip name/ids.

I have the name of my resource group and the name of the machine itself. Moreover, I've found vm's NIC using the command:

```
vmNIC=$(az vm nic list --resource-group $rgName --vm-name $vmName --query [].id -o tsv);
```

And found vm's disks (OS and data) using the commands:

```
vmOSDisk=$(az vm show -d -g $rgName -n $vmName --query "storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.id" -o tsv);
vmDataDisks=$(az vm show -d -g $rgName -n $vmName --query "storageProfile.dataDisks[].managedDisk.id" -o tsv);
```

Does anyone know how can I retrieve the name/ids of my virtual machine's NSG and my virtual machine's Public IP?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the VM's public IP, you can use

```
vmNIC=$(az vm nic list --resource-group $rgName --vm-name $vmName --query [].id -o tsv)
az network nic show --ids $vmNIC --query "ipConfigurations[].publicIpAddress.id" -o tsv
```

To retrieve the name/ids of the virtual machine's NSG, you can use

The nic level NSG,

```
az network nic show --ids $vmNIC --query "networkSecurityGroup.id" -o tsv
```

The subnet level NSG,

```
subnetID=$(az network nic show --ids $vmNIC --query "ipConfigurations[].subnet.id" -o tsv)
az network vnet subnet show --ids $subnetID --query "networkSecurityGroup.id" -o tsv
```